# How to check if a node is linked to another one?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, networkx, nan

I have a dataset built by extracting data from external sources. The output is like this

```
Node       Target
Jennifer   Maria
Luke       Mark
Johnny     nan
Ludo       Martin
Maria      nan
Mark       Luke
Mark       Christopher
```

and so on

When I built a network using networkx, since the target field for some of my nodes is null, I have isolated nodes, while there should be linked to a source node (e.g., `Maria` to `Jennifer`).
I am considering directed network, but even if it was undirected, the problem would still persist since, when I load as nodes list the `Nodes` column, I get nodes with `nan` value in the `Target` linked to a node called nan.
My question is: is there a way to check if the nodes within the Node column have a link (at least), looking at the Target column?
Happy to provide more information.

My expected output would be

```
Node       Target
Jennifer   Maria
Luke       Mark
Johnny     nan
Ludo       Martin
Maria      Jennifer
Mark       Luke
Mark       Christopher
```

In order to correctly create the network.

Comment: Creating an undirected graph from your original adjacency list (skipping rows where the target is `nan`) would still have a link between Jennifer and Maria. Not sure I see the problem :)

Comment: Hi AKX, thank you for your comment. The problem is that Maria and Jennifer are not linked (at least, Maria is linked to nan node). I am still keeping nan values, but only for those nodes that actually have no neighbours (for example Johnny). Please let me know if you have any questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) find `Target` where `NaN` values,
(b) find `Node` from `a` in `Target`.
(c) replace NaN by `Node` from `b`
and update your original dataframe.

```
a = df.loc[df['Target'].isnull()]
b = df[df['Target'].isin(a['Node'])]
b = b.rename(columns={'Node': 'Target', 'Target': 'Node'})
c = pd.merge(a['Node'], b, how='left', on='Node').set_index(a.index)
df.update(c)
```

```
>>> a
     Node Target
2  Johnny    NaN
4   Maria    NaN

>>> b
     Target   Node
0  Jennifer  Maria

>>> c
     Node    Target
2  Johnny       NaN
4   Maria  Jennifer

>>> df
       Node       Target
0  Jennifer        Maria
1      Luke         Mark
2    Johnny          NaN  # <- NaN
3      Ludo       Martin
4     Maria     Jennifer  # <- Jennifer
5      Mark         Luke
6      Mark  Christopher
```

---

**Old Answer**
As suggested by @AKX, remove rows with `NaN` before build the graph:

```
import networkx as nx

edges = df[df.notna().all(1)]

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(edges, source='Node', target='Target')
```

```
>>> G.edges
EdgeView([('Jennifer', 'Maria'), ('Luke', 'Mark'),
          ('Mark', 'Christopher'), ('Ludo', 'Martin')])
```

Comment: Thank you Corralien. To be honest, i  would prefer to keep nan values, but only those ones that actually do not have a match node/Target (like johnny in my example). The reason is that they provide also some info. However, if I consider the example with Maria, this is a misleading information, since Maria actually has a neighbour (Jennifer). Sorry if there has been some misunderstanding in my explanation

Comment: @V_sqrt. I updated my answer to get your expected outcome.

Comment: Thank you so much, Corralien! Yes, this is the approach I was thinking of (just wrote a comment to the other user). May I ask you if this approach could be extended also in case a node with nan value has more neighbours when it is target? Thanks for the help provided

Comment: Probably yes even if I don't know how yet :)